# Pinax Email Verification not working

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have installed `pinax` on my local and I try to sign-up on it. but the email verification is not working, so I look over the internet on how to config about the email verification but failed.

I try also the `forgot password` but it requires the email address to be confirmed.

I also try to put this code in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = '...'
EMAIL_PORT = ..
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '...'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '..'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '..'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_ADMIN = '...'
```

but still not working.

Does anyone have an idea on why my pinax's email verification is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your spam folder?

Also some apps tell Django to silently ignore EMail sending errors.
Try this [quick example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#quick-example) in the shell you get from `python manage.py shell` and see if it shows you any errors.

Comment: thanks Maccesch for the answer.. I try it the shell and it returns `1` but I did not receive the email...

Comment: In this case it probably is caught by your spam filter or a custom filter.

Comment: ahh.. so where can i find the spam filter?

Comment: In your email client/webinterface.

Comment: It's not there, my email receive any spam messages but i did not receive messages from my `pinax project`. btw, I try your answer in my other `django project` that not using `pinax` and i receive the mail. But in my `pinax` project, it returns `1` but I did not receive the mail.

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry I cannot think of anything else except some typo in your settings or email adress.